# Excel COUNTIFS Issue

Tags: excel, countif, named-ranges

`=COUNT(Due_Date<IF(ISBLANK(Final_Report_Date),Due_Date-1,Final_Report_Date))` gave me the result 1 which is correct.

But when i use `=COUNTIF(Due_Date,"<"&IF(ISBLANK(Final_Report_Date),Due_Date-1,Final_Report_Date))` it gave me 131. Why those two does not return the same result?

Both Due_Date, and Final_Report_Date are named range.

Comment: Does Due_Date refer to a range of more than one cell? Or to a single cell?

Comment: Both are named range.

Comment: A Named Range can refer to a single cell as well as to a range of more than one cell, so that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, it is a range of cells.

Comment: Your first formula is logically flawed, and will always return 1, no matter what values the ranges contain. Suggest you test this yourself.

Comment: Does your construction of the criteria in the second actually work?

Comment: what i am trying to do trying to check due date < final report date, but there are some blanks for final report date, then i will exclude those. The result should be 1 but it is giving me 131.

Comment: @XORLX, yeah you are correct. It is a coincidence that it gave me correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such comparisons are best handled by `SUMPRODUCT`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(Due_Date<N(+Final_Report_Date)))`

Regards

Comment: It works perfectly. But don't understand how it works. Sorry, i just learn excel like 4 months ago. Sumproduct is to multiple one array with another array to my understand. Could you explain me how your formula works?